# Splitting a list inside Python

Tags: python, list, function

There is a code:

```
def readData():
   file = open('data.txt', 'r')
   listing = []
   for line in file:
      print(line.split())
      depart = line.split()
      m = [line.strip()]
      listing.append(m)

   file.close()
   return listing

def display():
    depart = readData()
    poorest = []
    if int(depart[1]) <= int(depart[2])+int(depart[3]):
        poorest.append(depart[0])
    print(poorest)
```

The 'depart' output will produce this:

```
 [['Ladies  250 184 196'], ['Gentlemen  167 321 459'], ['Toys \t180 150 210'], ['Beauty\t450 280 320'], ['Technology\t169 320 279'], ['Home\t120 58 45'], ['Appliances\t210 130 67'], ['Food\t180 45 89'], ['Shoes\t260 100 210'], ['Children 179 50 80']]
```

But I need to produce something like this:

```
  ['Ladies',  '250', '184,  '196']
```

for each one. How should I change the second function?

Comment: try this instead `poorest.append(depart[0].split())` here you are splitting the given strings at spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or more `pythonic`

```
def ReadData():
    file = open('data.txt', 'r')
    listing = [[part.strip() for part in line.split()] for line in file]
    file.close()
    return listing
```

Read about [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Next we need to convert `str` to `int`

```
[[part.strip() if idx == 0 else int(part.strip())
  for idx, part in enumerate(line.split())]
 for line in file]
```

Now we have list:

```
[['Ladies', 250, 184, 196], ['Gentlemen', 167, 321, 459], ...
```

Comment: It works, thanks!
And one more question: how can I compare numbers inside these nested lists? I will really appreciate if you can help me. I tried to do this myself, but I failed.

Answer (score 0):

You're not appending a split list to the list that you're eventually returning, so if you change the lines below

```
depart = line.split()
m = [line.strip()]
listing.append(m)
```

to

```
listing.append(line.strip().split())
```

you'll get what you wanted.